# $resource calls to url failing in simple angularjs app built in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, url, angularjs, resources

I mostly followed Ryan Bates' setup for a angular app in rails.  In my gemfile:

```
gem 'angularjs-rails'
```

and in the application.js:

```
//= require angular
//= require angular-resource
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Here is what I believe is all the relevant code from views/pages.home.html:

```
<body data-ng-app="dithat">
  <div class="container" data-ng-controller="accomplishmentController">
    <p> What'd you do? </p>
    <form ng-submit="submit()">
      <input type="text" ng-model="newAccomp" />
    </form>
    <div data-ng-repeat="accomp in accomplishments | filter:newAccomp" >
      <div class="box" ng-click="addToCount()">
        <div class="accomplishment">
          {{ accomp.name }}
          <a href="#" ng-click="delete()" class="x">x</a>
          <p class="count"> {{ accomp.count }} </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  

  <script type="text/javascript">
    app = angular.module("dithat", ["ngResource"]);
    function accomplishmentController($scope, $resource) { 
      Entry = $resource('/api/users.json');
      console.log(Entry.query());
      $scope.accomplishments = [];
      $scope.submit = function() {
        $scope.accomplishments.unshift({ name: $scope.newAccomp, count: 0 });
        $scope.newAccomp = '';
      }
      $scope.addToCount = function() {
        var currentcount = this.accomp.count;
        this.accomp.count = currentcount + 1;
      }
      $scope.delete = function() {
        index = this.$index;
        $scope.accomplishments.splice(index, 1)
      }
    }

  </script>  
</body>
```

The code works, as in the app is behaving how it should, however it is not making the resource call.  I tried this with `$http` as well and it didn't work either.   What am I missing??!!  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you tested that the code is working, and where you are looking and seeing that the resource call is not made? Looking at this code, you are not registering a controller with angular. You have just defined a function that can be used as a controller. Are you missing `app.controller('accomplishmentController', accomplishmentController)`?

Comment: Good :). I'll add this as a proper answer then.

Comment: can i ask one more question even though this is maybe a different question?   it's making the call but the call is returning an empty array.  localhost:3000/api/users returns a json object that is from the users controller where @users = User.all and i render :json.  What is wrong with the query?

Comment: I think should probably be a separate question, but I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368465/angular-http-call-not-binding-on-success-to-scope-data/19368633#19368633) could help. Also if you are expecting an object you should be using `Entry.get()` rather than `Entry.query`. See [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource) - query has `isArray: true`

Comment: ok thanks for the direction, does this look right to you?  Entry = $resource('/api/users');
    users = Entry.query(function() {

    });
    console.log(users);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39306/discussion-between-andyrooger-and-natecraft1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comment:

The `accomplishmentController` function is defined but it still needs to be registered with angular using

```
app.controller('accomplishmentController', accomplishmentController)
```

otherwise it will not be able to be used (and won't necessarily cause any errors).